# Make a Zorin OS + Windows 11 dual boot without decrypting everything

Tags: windows, dual-boot, system-installation, zorin

I'm new to Linux, and I want to install Zorin OS to make a Windows 11 + Zorin OS dual boot, but my hard drive is encrypted by BitLocker. Is there a way of doing that without decrypting everything?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way of doing that:

I had an unused partition on my computer, so I deleted it, and started the Zorin OS installer.
Then, I created some partitions on that free space, and installed Zorin OS there!
It worked fine, except that when booting Windows for the first time after installing Zorin OS, it couldn't find the BitLocker key, but recovering it was quite easy!